# ASP.NET Core Visual Studio 2015 Virtual applications debug

Tags: asp.net

I have a Azure site and have create a Virtual applications under the site:

xxx.yyy.com/test

I deploy my ASP.NET application into this directory.

But how can I have the same setup when I do debug in Visual Studio. When I hit F5 would I like to have the application "deployed" and run in localhost:5000/test, and not localhost:5000.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it that you find the answer 2 sec after you post a question?

Open the applicationhost.config for the solution, it is hidden in the .vs folder.

Find the application tag. Copy and add a new application tag and change the path from / to /test. On the first application tag did I change the physicalPath to something else.

```
<site name="xxx.yyy" id="2">
  <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\" />
  </application>
  <application path="/test" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\Project\xxx\src\xx.yy" />
  </application>
  <bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:5001:localhost" />
  </bindings>
</site>
```